# How to display the paths to all files that have a size greater than the specified limit

Tags: bash, files, find, size

I need to output the paths to all files that have a size greater than the specified limit (declared as a variable).

I've done it using find script:

```
FILESIZE = "+10M";
find "$1" -maxlimit 1 -size "$FILESIZE" -type f -exec echo "put {}" \;
```

And it give me 2 errors:

```
/mnt/d/Lab1_z2.sh: line 1: FILESIZE: command not found

find: unknown predicate `-maxlimit'
```

How to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

The first error is simple:

```
# wrong:
FILESIZE = "+10M";
# correct:
FILESIZE="+10M"
```

You should not surround `=` sign with spaces in assigning shell variables. Another problem - semicolon at the end of the line is not needed. It does not hurt, but not needed.

The second error is actually puzzling - where did you get that option? There is no `-maxlimit` option in `find`. To learn all possible keys and options, do `man find` and read.

Comment: Oops, I've meant `-maxdepth`